# batch pointing to JAR doesnt execute with newest java version

Tags: java, batch-file, exe

I have a JAR, which can be executed via a .bat file containing the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\javaw.exe" (
     "%JAVA_HOME%\javaw.exe" -jar foo.jar 
) else (
    "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" -jar foo.jar 
)

exit
```

This worked fine up to Java 1.8.0_91. However, after updating to 1.8.0_101 suddenly it is not possible anymore to open the .bat file with a double-click. The program only starts when the user rights-clicks -> run as administrator.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run in the console `x.bat >out.txt 2>err.txt` to capture what happens? The JAVA_HOME is to suspect.

Comment: running the bat with cmd started as an admin just gives "access denied". Running cmd as an admin with the above starts the program with two empty txt-files. I just wonder why I suddenly have to start it as an admni

Comment: Fill in `%JAVA_HOME%` and try `java.exe`. Maybe some missing install for all users?

Comment: that works! now i just need a generic way to create the path to java... what do you mean with missing install for all users? path variable not set correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a Windows guru, Maybe just double quotes were missing in the JAVA_HOME string or around all. But if it works as admin... or written out... There still is the choice between JDK and JRE and between 64 bits and 32 bits.